# Async/await nested await

Tags: c#, async-await

The below code was taken from a [Microsoft help document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-return-types). I've changed it slightly, but not in a significant way. The original code did mark `Main()` as `async`, which I understand makes a big difference.

1. I'm trying to understand why when 1a is uncommented while 1b is commented then `"You rolled"` is not displayed.  When the situation is reversed (1a is commented and 1b is uncommented) then `"You rolled"` is displayed after a second of delay. I understand that in the first case the call to `PlayAsync()` in `Main` does its computations on a `ThreadPool` thread while `Main()` finishes and terminates the program - so no display. In the second case, `PlayAsync()` appears to run on the main (not `ThreadPool`) thread - why?  While in first case "awaiting" is clearly taking place, is "awaiting" taking place in the second case or are all those "awaits" ignored (if so, why)?
2. To clarify how async/await works. In the shown program structure, is each nested `await` statement executed on a different thread?  Documentation states that `await` keyword causes the statement that follows to be executed on a `ThreadPool` thread and the thread that called the method continues execution past the method call.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly Random s_rnd = new Random();

    public static void Main()
    {
        PlayAsync();
    }

    public static async Task PlayAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"You rolled {await GetDiceRollAsync()}"); //2 T1?
    }

    static async Task<int> GetDiceRollAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shaking dice...");

        int roll1 = await RollAsync(); //2 T2?
        int roll2 = await RollAsync(); //2 T3?

        return roll1 + roll2;
    }

    static async Task<int> RollAsync()
    {
        //1a await Task.Delay(500); /*uncomment, "You rolled " is not displayed*/
        //1b Thread.Sleep(500); /*uncomment, "You rolled " is displayed after delay*/

        int diceRoll = s_rnd.Next(1, 7);
        return diceRoll;
    }
}
```

Comment: `await` will only actually be asynchronous when the thing you're awaiting hasn't already completed. If you remove `Task.Delay` there's *nothing asynchronous at all* in your code. (So everything will indeed run on the main thread.) But no, there's no concept of "each nested await is executed on a different thread". I'd strongly advise going through MS tutorials/articles about async, really carefully.

Comment: Your code may not print anything at all. Calling an async method without awaiting it is like "fire and forget", you calling method (main in the case) will continue its work after calling `PlayAsync`, but as long as `PlayAsync` is the only thing in your main, it will just stop execution after this call.

Comment: Jon Skeet. I've added a link to the MS doc. As to the first comment, I thought that including "await" indicates to the compiler (which will translate async/await) that if the code that is being "awaited" runs longer than some predetermined time (50ms from memory) then it should be moved onto ThreadPool thread from that point onward so as not to tie up the main thread.  That's why the "Thread.Sleep" statement.

Comment: What confuses me is that it seems like there should be a special statement at the end of a nested "await" otherwise no "awaiting" happens.  In //1a that special statement is await Task.Delay(500), but what is special in Task.Delay() implementation that doesn't cause the behavior of //1b, which is just a plain Thread.Sleep() call.  Compiler tells me that if there is no await in async then the "async" method is going to be called synchronously, but what about all those "awaits" that happened earlier in the call stack?  Are they now ignored just because the most nested method does not have await?

Comment: No, it doesn't do anything like "if the awaited code runs for an amount of time is moves to the thread pool". Nothing like that at all. But I'm not going to explain the details of async/await in a comment thread - or even in an answer, as there are *lots* of detailed documents about it already. If you read all the documentation carefully, all your questions will be answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question after carefully reading [How Async/Await Really Works in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/).

The answer may be helpful to everyone else who might be confused similarly to how I was when asking the question.

The purpose of `async/await` is to relieve the programmer from having to write a bunch of repetitive (pattern) code that can get difficult to follow to achieve asynchronicity; the compiler does that for us now.  The compiler uses patterns and APIs to achieve that.

`async/await` is translated by the compiler into a *state machine*.  The `async` function's code is converted into a method of the *state machine*.  The `async` and `await` are not executable statements, but rather instructions to the compiler.  The mechanism is similar to how the `yield` statement is translated.  At runtime, each call to an `async` function instantiates (creates object on the heap, though cached versions can be used in specific scenarios) the *state machine* defined for the function at compile time.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but unless you have an `await` keyword in an `async` function, no *state machine* will be defined for that function.

Given the above, my question's code sample would instantiate 2 or 3 (depending on 1a/1b) distinct *state machines*.

An `async` function must return a type that is decorated with `[AsyncMethodBuilder...]` or `void`.  `void` is allowed so that event handlers in UI code can be marked `async`.  Value type returns are also possible but I'm not getting into that.

An `async` function can have any number of `await` keywords and still a single *state machine* will be defined for it.  The `await` keyword can be applied to any function that returns a type that is **awaitable**.  A type is **awaitable** if it exposes the `GetAwaiter()` method, which is part of the **"awaiter"** pattern.

The actual asynchronicity (multi-threading) comes not from the `async/await` translation but the **awaited** function that returns an **awaitable** type.  The function that is being **awaited** will internally decide whether to execute it's code on a separate thread or not and the returned type will indicate how the function was executed and whether it is still running or has already completed.

At an `await` line, the thread executing the `async` function will call the **awaited** function.  The **awaited** function will return an **awaitable** type.  The returned type's completion status will be checked.  If it is completed, the next statement in the `async` function will be executed (on the current thread) otherwise the `async` function will return and the caller of the `async` function will resume execution.  In this case, the *state machine* will execute the rest of the `async` function on a separate thread, after the **awaited** function completes.  This is called a *continuation*.

If the **awaited** function executes it's code on the same thread that called it, then we are essentially running synchronously and the **awaitable** return type will be available after the **awaited** function finishes.  On the other hand, if the **awaited** function executes it's code on another thread (`ThreadPool` for instance), then we are running asynchronously and the **awaitable** return type is available to the current thread immediately.  The asynchronous work may complete before the current thread gets a chance to examine the status of the returned **awaitable** type in which case the current thread will continue executing the remainder of the `async` function (synchronously).

If there are multiple `await` statements in an `async` function, before the next `await` statement can execute, the previous one must complete first.

So the question of whether each `await` executes on a different thread is really up to the function that is being **awaited** and not the `async/await` *state machine*.

For an `async` function we can have from 0 to many additional (to the current thread) thread executions:

- "0" when the **awaited** function is synchronous.
- The "number of threads started" in the **awaited** function when it finishes prior to the current thread checking the status of the returned **awaitable** type's completion status.
- The "number of threads started" in the **awaited** function plus "1" thread for the *continuation* when the returned **awaitable** type has not completed at time of checking.

`async Main()` vs `Main()` as pertaining to my example.
`PlayAsync()` returns an **awaitable** type.  If `Main()` does not explicitly wait for that type to finish then it may exit while `PlayAsync()` is still running, effectively cancelling `PlayAsync()` before it finishes.  To have `Main()` wait for an **awaitable** type, mark `Main()` as `async` and call using `await PlayAsync();` (to create a *state machine*) or store/reference the **awaitable** type returned by `PlayAsync()` and call it's `Wait()` method - `PlayAsync().Wait();`  If `PlayAsync()` is not asynchronous, case 1b, then the thread executing `Main()` will also execute `PlayAsync()` to completion hence we have a result.

To avoid excess object allocations while utilizing `async/await` various framework and compiler optimizations are employed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `await` the call at the top of the call stack.

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{
  await PlayAsync();
}
```

With async/await, you really must go all the way.